# Getting matching records from mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have database table with the following structure, that is used to match people at a dating event:

```
ID | EVENT | USERS_ID | MATCH_ID | GENDER
1 | 27 | 54 | 1245 | Female
2 | 27 | 54 | 21 | Female
3 | 27 | 21 | 45 | Male
4 | 27 | 21 | 54 | Male
```

I am trying to write my query that will give me my matches.
For example, from the data above, user 54 matches user 21 because 54 picked 21 and 21 picked 54.

I need to pass as an input a USER_ID and the EVENT and get a list of the MATCH_ID that match that user.
So,

```
SELECT match_id FROM……. WHERE users_id = 54 AND event = 27
```

I also need to know which users DIDN’T get any matches. This would be a separate query. From the example above, user 45 had no mutual matches.

I’ve been fighting with this one for a while. Any ideas on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should do it for you:

```
SELECT t2.users_id FROM 
tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2
ON t1.users_id = t2.match_id AND t1.match_id = t2.users_id
WHERE t2.event = 27
AND t1.users_id = 54;
```

Also, for finding all the users who don't have any matches, this would probably work:

```
SELECT t1.match_id
FROM
tbl t1
LEFT JOIN 
tbl t2
ON t1.match_id = t2.users_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

The general principle here though, is to join the table to itself, and find matches that way.

EDIT: Made some corrections, feel pretty confident this should work well for you.

EDIT 2: Here is the final correction, which I believe should pull this all together for you.

SELECT * FROM 
event_matches t1
INNER JOIN event_matches t2
ON t1.users_id = t2.matches AND t1.matches = t2.users_id AND t1.event_id = t2.event_id
WHERE t2.event_id = 45
AND t1.users_id = 1239;

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's almost there, but something strange happens with more users:

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's almost there, but something strange happens when you search for a user that made no selections. On my data set above if you search for matches for users_id = 1245 it picks up other users. And I added a DISTINCT on the main SELECT.

Comment: Hmm, not getting same results. Loaded data set into test table, ran same query, with 1245, get no results. Also tried with DISTINCT keyword, also no results. Perhaps different results, on bigger data set as you suggested? Could look at entire data set to figure something out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is the real data set I am working with
[link]http://www.playstone.net/downloads/matches_export.txt

If you run your query (I have it on that file as well) and have t1.users_id = 1249 it will pickup use 1283 but it should return an empty results as this user has no matches.

Thanks again @user470714

Comment: Hate sounding like broken record, but still ... getting good results on my end. Tried your SQL dump, and got expected results with any parameters, i.e. only 1244 and 1282 are interested in each other. Noted though, there's still only 5 rows in the table. Are there more in the real table? I wonder if mysql version makes any difference at all. I'm using 5.1.

Comment: That's really weird. I'm running MySQL 5.0.45. I have updated that .txt file with a full export of the entire table. Sorry about this. This is the last hurdle to finish this project :-( @user470714

Comment: I see the problem = )   It's the event ID. Have to match on that too. Check out the EDITED answer.

Comment: Alright!!! That was it. Thank you so much. Saved me a ton of time on this one. I have to brush up on my INNER JOINS. Thanks again. Bruno.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help! Once you really get the concept of the JOINs down, your SQL-Fu will level up majorly.